# Retrofit response does not show

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit

My Retrofit response is not shown at first, but only when I navigate out of my application and return to it. If I, after going to another activity, return to the activity with the data, the data would also go away. Do any of you have had this problem?

Here is my function

```
private fun makeRetrofit(){
    //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "This is from makeRetrofit function start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    val myretrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://noelvillaman.com/about/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    val api = myretrofit.create(Api::class.java)

    val call = api.getUnits()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<UnitObject>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<UnitObject>>, response: Response<List<UnitObject>>) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.isSuccessful.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful){
                var units = response.body()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                if (units != null) {
                    for (unit in units) {
                        Log.d("unit", unit.getUnit())
                        Log.d("vocabulary", unit.getVocabulary().toString())
                        Log.d("grammar", unit.getGrammar())
                        Log.d("idioms", unit.getIdioms())
                        val subjects = Subjects(unit.getUnit(), unit.getVocabulary(), unit.getGrammar(), unit.getIdioms())
                        //dataSubjects.add(subjects)
                        completeList.add(subjects)


                    }

                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<UnitObject>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    })
}
```

Here are some screenshots of what I am trying to describe.

[When the app first opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX7QW.jpg)

[When I navigate away from it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yWbW.jpg)

[When I return to the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWKD7.jpg)

Comment: Where do you call `makeRetrofit`?

Comment: Please add items to your adapter and use notifyDatasetChange() in your adapter after adding elements.

Comment: I call it in onCreate() function.

Comment: Shubhamgarg1, I am not changing anything to the list, I just want to see the content. I never make any change. I also did what you mention, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Scarboro, I don't see any difference b/w two images you attached. Anyway from the code's side It's always good if you use a singleton for retrofit object and initialize it once in the lifetime of your application since the httpClient Creation during retrofit initialization is a costly operation.

And can you please attach you logs screen shot, do you get any logs.

- If you are getting the logs it means you are getting data.(API success)
- If not and unless you are getting the error Toast, it means the if condition in success call back is failing.

Comment: I do get the data, therefore there is not error in the log. I tried to shared the third image, but, for some reason, it did not allow me. I will try to add it.

Comment: Ok, once you get the data, what do you do after that. I think you have to store it somewhere and show it in the UI.

Comment: I have an arrayAdapter that shows the data in arrayList. I do it by calling this function: completeList.add(subjects).

Comment: Ok after adding you are calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Right?

Comment: No, I am new to this of retrofit, so I will find out how to use notifyDataSetChanged() later, it is the first time is see this.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is method in BaseAdapter that will reload the list once data item change occurs.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Thank you. I did not mention that when I see the log.d, I can see all the data I am looking for, so my only problem is showing them consistently.

Comment: Ambareesh B: I use this method after setting the adapter, and the problem persists.

Comment: Ok so you are calling API in wrong place, better you should call the API in activity onStart()

Comment: Wow, thank you for your help, but that does not work for me. It does the same thing, I even uninstalled the app.